# Creating Lotus Notes documents with specific created/modified/last accessed dates for testing

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

I'm currently writing an application that moves Notes documents between databases based on the amount of days that have elapsed from the creation/modified/last accessed dates. I would just like to get ideas on a simple and convenient way to create documents with specific dates, without having to change the time on the Domino server, so that I could test out my application.

The best way I found so far was to create a local replica and change the system clock to the date I want. Unfortunately there are problems associated with this method. It does not work on the modified date - I'm not sure how it is getting the modified date information when the location is set to *Island (Disconnected)* - and it also changes the modified and last accessed dates when the documents are replicated to the server replica.

Someone suggested trying to create a DXL of the document, modify the date time in the DXL file, then import it back into the database as a Notes document; but that does not work. It just takes on the date-time that it was created.

Can anyone offer any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the created date for a document by setting the UNID (which is fundamentally a struct of timestamps, although the actual implementation has changed in recent versions). Accessed and modified times, though, would be unsettable from within the Notes/Domino environment, since the changes you make would be overwritten by the process of saving the changes. If you have a flair for adventure and a need to run with scissors, you could make the changes in the database file itself either programmatically from an external application, or manually with a hex editor. (Editing the binary will work -- folks have been using hex editors to clear the "hide design" flag safely for years. Keep in mind that signed docs will blow up badly, and that you need to ensure that local encryption is off for the database file.)

Comment: upvote for this priceless caveat emptor: "If you have a flair for adventure and a need to run with scissors..."

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a very simple way to spoof the creation date/time: just add a field called $Created with whatever date/time you want.  This is alluded to in the Notes C API header file nsfdata.h:

> Time/dates associated with notes:
>           OID.Note                Can be Timedate when the note was created
>                                   (but not guaranteed to be - look for $CREATED
>                                   item first for note creation time)
>                                   Obtained by NSFNoteGetInfo(_NOTE_OID) or
>                                   OID in SEARCH_MATCH.

Unfortunately, there's no analogous technique for spoofing the mod or access dates.  At least none that's ever been documented, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine given how dependent Lotus Notes is on timestamps (for replication, mainly), there isn't an API call that allows you to change the modified, created, or last access dates of a note.  (More on the internals of Lotus Notes can be found [here](http://www.angelfire.com/ult/tipslotusnotes/The%20Architecture%20of%20Lotus%20Notes.htm).)

I dug around the Notes C API documentation, and found only one mention on how to [get/set information in the note's header](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/6.5/api65ref.nsf/852561bd0045e8e785255b3c005a57bb/85255d56004d3f6385255bd5000d1c87?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,modified), including the modified date.  However, the documentation states that when you try to update that note (i.e. write it to disk), the last modified date will be overwritten with the date/time it is written to disk.

As an alternative, I would suggest creating your own set of date items within the documents that only you control, for example MyCreated, MyModified, and MyAccessed, and reference those in your code that moves documents based on dates.  You would then be able to change these dates as easily as changing any other document item (via agents, forms, etc.)

For MyCreated, create a hidden calculated form field with the formula of @CREATED or @NOW.  Set the type to computed when composed.

For MyModified, create a hidden calculated form field with the formula @NOW, and set the type to computed.

MyAccessed gets a bit tricky.  If you can do without it, I suggest you live work with just the MyCreated and MyModified.  If you need it, you *should* be able to manage it by setting a field value within the QueryOpen or PostOpen events.  Problems occur if your users have only read access to a document - the code to update the MyAccessed field won't be able to store that value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I found your links quite informative - although I am not too keen on the idea of creating custom fields as a solution to the problem. This is because I encountered a database in the past where someone did this and they coded the application in such a way where the fields where not updating correctly. This was causing confusion in the search results when users viewed the document's properties.

Comment: It is definitely a concern.  You're not really hooking up to the correct events with the solution I proposed.  You would need instead something like an Insert and Update trigger in SQL.  Unfortunately, there's no way to do that in Notes in one place, so you would have to make sure you cover all cases where the document is created or updated.  It is definitely possible if you are familiar with all the code, but I understand your hesitation.